# Getting Error Eventhough entered correct statement

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT(STID INT,SNAME CHAR(10),SALARY MONEY);

INSERT INTO STUDENT(1,'SMITH',3000);
```

Table created successfully but getting error while inserting the values into the table

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.
> Completion time: 2023-06-19T19:46:31.9527099-04:00

I want to enter the values into the table.

Comment: The INSERT statement doesn't seem to be correct

Answer (score 1):

If you try specifying the column names after the table name `(STUDENT)`. Then specify the `VALUES` clause provide the corresponding values for the columns.

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT(STID, SNAME, SALARY) 
VALUES (1, 'SMITH', 3000);
```